# Como calcular distância percorrida por mim em swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, gps

estou tentando calcular a distância que percorro entre meu ponto inicial, até o momento que eu paro minha corrida/troco de tela. Podem me ajudar? Segue abaixo as partes mais relevantes do código.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapa: MKMapView!
var gerenciadorLocalizacao = CLLocationManager()
@IBOutlet weak var velocidadeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var enderecoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tempoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var distanciaLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var caloriasLabel: UILabel!
lazy var timer = Timer()
var segundos = 0.0
var distancia = 0.0
var calorias = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gerenciadorLocalizacao.delegate = self
    gerenciadorLocalizacao.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    gerenciadorLocalizacao.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    gerenciadorLocalizacao.startUpdatingLocation()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(self.atualizaSegundo(timer:)),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: true)

}


func atualizaSegundo(timer: Timer) {

    segundos += 1
    let quantidadeSegundos = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.second(), doubleValue: segundos)
    tempoLabel.text = quantidadeSegundos.description

    let quantidadeDistancia = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.meter(), doubleValue: distancia)
    distanciaLabel.text = quantidadeDistancia.description

    let quantidadeCalorias = HKQuantity(unit:HKUnit.kilocalorie(), doubleValue: calorias)
    caloriasLabel.text = quantidadeCalorias.description

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let localizacaoUsuario = locations.last!

    let longitude = localizacaoUsuario.coordinate.longitude
    let latitude = localizacaoUsuario.coordinate.latitude

    if localizacaoUsuario.speed > 0 {
        velocidadeLabel.text = String( localizacaoUsuario.speed )
    }

    let deltaLat: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let deltaLon: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let localizacao: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let areaExibicao: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(deltaLat, deltaLon)
    let regiao: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(localizacao, areaExibicao)
    mapa.setRegion(regiao, animated: true)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation( localizacaoUsuario) { (detalhesLocal, erro) in

        if erro == nil {

            if let dadosLocal = detalhesLocal?.first {

                var thoroughfare = ""
                if dadosLocal.thoroughfare != nil {
                    thoroughfare = dadosLocal.thoroughfare!
                }

                var subThoroughfare = ""
                if dadosLocal.subThoroughfare != nil {
                    subThoroughfare = dadosLocal.subThoroughfare!
                }

                var locality = ""
                if dadosLocal.locality != nil {
                    locality = dadosLocal.locality!
                }

                var subLocality = ""
                if dadosLocal.subLocality != nil {
                    subLocality = dadosLocal.subLocality!
                }

                var postalCode = ""
                if dadosLocal.postalCode != nil {
                    postalCode = dadosLocal.postalCode!
                }

                var country = ""
                if dadosLocal.country != nil {
                    country = dadosLocal.country!
                }

                var administrativeArea = ""
                if dadosLocal.administrativeArea != nil {
                    administrativeArea = dadosLocal.administrativeArea!
                }

                var subAdministrativeArea = ""
                if dadosLocal.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                    subAdministrativeArea = dadosLocal.subAdministrativeArea!
                }

                self.enderecoLabel.text = thoroughfare + " - "
                                          + subThoroughfare + " / "
                                          + locality + " / "
                                          + country

                print(
                        "\n / Endereço:" + thoroughfare +
                        "\n / Número Aprox:" + subThoroughfare +
                        "\n / Estado:" + locality +
                        "\n / Bairro:" + subLocality +
                        "\n / CEP:" + postalCode +
                        "\n / País:" + country +
                        "\n / Estado:" + administrativeArea +
                        "\n / Região:" + subAdministrativeArea
                        )
                    }
                }else{
            print(erro)
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status != .authorizedWhenInUse {

        let alertaController = UIAlertController(title: "Permissão de localização",
                                                 message: "Precisamos ter acesso a sua localização, por favor habilite o GPS",
                                                 preferredStyle: .alert )

        let acaoConfiguracoes = UIAlertAction(title: "Configurações", style: .default , handler: { (alertaConfiguracoes) in

            if let configuracoes = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString ) {
                UIApplication.shared.open( configuracoes as URL )
            }

        })

        let acaoCancelar = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .default , handler: nil )

        alertaController.addAction( acaoConfiguracoes )
        alertaController.addAction( acaoCancelar )

        present( alertaController , animated: true, completion: nil )


    }

}
```

Comment: Não use timers pra calcular tempo. O correto é armazenar a data inicial `let startDate = Date()` e usar a instance property `timeIntervalSinceNow` da sua Data `startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow` O resultado por ser passado vai sempre ser negativo. Uma solução é usar o método timeIntervalSince(date:) da seguinte forma `var segundos: TimeInterval { return  Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate) }`

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma função pronta para calcular a distância entre dois pontos de CLLocation:

```
let distance = currentLocation.distance(from: initialLocation)
```

O resultado é dado em CLLocationDistance, que é a distância entre os dois pontos em metros.

Se quiser ler a documentação, segue o link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance.

Comment: muito obrigado Andressa, obrigado mesmo! Consegui!

Comment: De nada! Pode dar um vote up, por favor?

Comment: Já votei Andressa, mas ainda não tenho reputação suficiente rs acabei de entrar :/

Comment: hahaha Obrigada!! ;)